Printing specific items from Python Shell
I have this code:
import subprocess
activescheme = subprocess.check_output('powercfg -getactivescheme')
print(str(activescheme, encoding='cp866'))

And this output:
GUID схемы питания: 22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222  (Высокая производительность)

I want to check this the output ad then print message in tkinter, but I coildn't. So I think that I can take only words from brackets and print them in tk. I don't know how to do this
I tried this but didn't get a result, the output was No
import subprocess
activescheme = subprocess.check_output('powercfg -getactivescheme')
print(str(activescheme, encoding='cp866'))
if activescheme == "GUID схемы питания: 22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222  (Высокая производительность)":
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")

Help, please

There's probably a newline at the end of the output. Use activescheme.strip() to remove it.

Note that activescheme is of type bytes, not string. So the comparison will be evaluated as False.
You can either converting activescheme to string before comparison:
activescheme = activescheme.decode("cp866")
if activescheme == "Power Scheme GUID: fb5220ff-7e1a-47aa-9a42-50ffbf45c673  (HP Optimized (Modern Standby))":
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")

Or comparing with an array of bytes:
if activescheme == b"Power Scheme GUID: fb5220ff-7e1a-47aa-9a42-50ffbf45c673  (HP Optimized (Modern Standby))":
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")


Thak you very much! It works for me
